# Trying to enlarge menu text when the menu is hovered over

Tags: html, css

very schoolboy error here but I cannot seem to get it working.

What I'm after is when you hover over a specific list in the menu the text in that menu increases in size, however at the moment it *only* increases size when you hover the text and not the actual 'box' that the text is in.

```
ul li :hover{
font-size: 30px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}


ul li a{
font-size: 20px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the :hover pseudo-selector to be directly after the `li` and then also select the `a` to get the effect on the hover over the li. Note that I added a line-height of the larger size to allow the text to increase in size without causing a jump to the size of the li's.

```css
ul li {
  list-style:none;
  height:30px;
}

ul li a{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:30px;
}

ul li:hover a{
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href = "#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href = "#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href = "#">Three</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu {
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.menu a {
  font-size:14px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  font-size:30px;
}


.menu2 {
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:20px;
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
}

.menu2 a {
  font-size:14px;
}

.menu2 a:hover {
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
Box will expand
<br />
<br />
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#">test 2</a>
</div>



Box will not expand
<br />
<br />
<div class="menu2">
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#">test 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not clear to me. But I think you want to achive something like this..

```
ul li{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    width:80px;
}

ul li a:hover{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li><a>Item1</a></li>
    <li><a>Item2</a></li>
    <li><a>Item3</a></li>
</ul>
```